# Android development large app resources

Tags: updates, android

We will be building an application that will contain lots of assets that contain hundreds of images and videos.  We will be side loading the initial application because of its size.

For security reason we want the media folder that contains the assets to be in the application root dir.

We already know features to be added later on so we will have to do upgrades. Is it possible to upgrade the application but include media that it initially contains?

If not how could we secure a folder outside of the application.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this isn't a very effective security mechanism - it's extremely easy to root almost any Android device, and on a rooted device users would have no difficulty getting at assets in your application root directory.

A better bet might be to encrypt your media assets somehow; that way, you can download them on startup rather than bundling them with the application, so the APK can stay small and the assets can easily be retained no an upgrade.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to encrypt images, videos.  Doesn't have to be crazy good security just enough to make it inconvenient to try to access it.

Comment: If you use [CipherInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) I think that would take care of most of the heavy lifting for you. Best choice of cipher is probably AES since that's hardware-accelerated on a lot of CPUs now (though I'm not 100% sure if Android takes advantage of that yet). Beyond that the main problem is finding a place in your app to hide the decryption key.

Comment: I would be pre encrypting all the content. The content would only be decrypted when it would be in use. I might store it in cache sometimes.
Thanks for the help. Ill look into how to encrypt it before hand and hopefully it can be decrypted on the device.